# Can't initialize crashlytics in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4, crashlytics, xcode11.3

Followed all instructions showed in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFQLG1Hlzis
As well as all instructions that are shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

My firebase connection is good, I'm able to see analytics, and use messaging, push notifications etc.

Im currently having issues connecting to crashlytics. If I do the following:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
```

I'm able to see the following debug output in the logs:

```
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 7.5.0
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.7.5.0 started
**[Fabric] [Crashlytics] Attempting to initialize Crashlytics via Firebase but could not find Crashlytics.**
```

This are my pods

```
Installing Firebase (7.5.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (7.5.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (7.5.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (7.5.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (7.5.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (7.5.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (7.5.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (7.5.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (7.5.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (8.2.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.2.2)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.12)
Installing nanopb (2.30907.0)
```

Im using Xcode 11.3.1 swift 4
Already doubled check my Google Info p list , and aldo checked the run script in the build phases and the documentation specifies.

Comment: Please try this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios

Answer (score 1):

You should not call Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric is finally dead.

To enable debug logging on your development device, specify the following command line argument in Xcode:
-FIRDebugEnabled
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?platform=ios#3111)

Comment: I still get the same error: "The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. " and "Attempting to initialize Crashlytics via Firebase but could not find Crashlytics."

Comment: if you need just crashreporting, you do not need AdSupport. so you can ignore that error.
if you link AdSupport framework, then firebase will have access to IDFA. And please check if you still have calls or import for Fabric, that should be removed completely.